# Replace one module by another by using JS and PHP in Joomla

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla

Extremely need your help. I have a page on my website with two modules with shows some articles. On the left side I have an Joomla article which inludes module that display some short news by using {loadposition} and at the right side module which displays long articles. I want to make a switcher that will replace module at my article by another module. My code that is not working correct is following

```html
 

<div id="mods">{loadposition mod1}</div>
<ul>
<li><a id="mod1" href="#mod1"><img /></a></li>
<li><a id="mod2" href="#mod2"><img /></a></li>
</ul>
```

And script which only change text and not loading module is following

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#mod1").click(function() {
    jQuery("#mods").html('{loadposition mod1}'); 
  });
  jQuery("#mod2").click(function() {
    jQuery("#mods").html('{loadposition mod2}'); 
  });  
});
```

I need to load another module mod2 instead mod1 that was loaded together with full page. Please help to make my script work correct.

Comment: Just put something clickable inside the anchor tags. Rather than using an empty <img /> tag, put an actual working image tag or add some text.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
<div id="mods">{loadposition mod1}</div>
<ul>
<li><a id="mod1" href="#mod1"><img /></a></li>
<li><a id="mod2" href="#mod2"><img /></a></li>
</ul>
```

`{loadposition mod1}` is used to load the module mod1 from server by parsing the code so if you use jQuery it will just change in the client PC but wont load a module. You may need ajax for that. best is to load both the modules and hide one module. When someone clicks the second image they see the other module. This can be a better option, but not tested by me:

```
<div id="mods1">{loadposition mod1}</div>
<div id="mods2" style="display: none">{loadposition mod2}</div>
 <ul>
    <li><a id="mod1" href="#mod1"><img /></a></li>
    <li><a id="mod2" href="#mod2"><img /></a></li>
 </ul>
```

My jQuery code will be

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#mod1").click(function() {
    $("#mods1").css("display", "block");
    $("#mods2").css("display", "none");
  });
  jQuery("#mod2").click(function() {
    $("#mods2").css("display", "block");
    $("#mods1").css("display", "none");
  });  
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know your method, but I going to load not only 2 modules but 15. And if I set to load them all, my page is starting for a long time